# Embedded document for Signing -Docu sign REST API

Tags: php, rest, docusignapi

I`m using REST api for embedding signing.I want to embedded a document for signing in the website for each user who logged into my website. For this I have created a Template and add some tags and set them as required. While creating the template in the 'Recipients and Routing' section I have provided only one signer email and name. For generating the url for embedded signing I have used the following code

```
<?php

// Input your info:
$email = "***";         // your account email
$password = "***";      // your account password
$integratorKey = "***";     // your account integrator key, found on (Preferences -> API page)
$recipientName = "***";     // provide a recipient (signer) name
$templateId = "***";        // provide a valid templateId of a template in your account
$templateRoleName = "***";  // use same role name that exists on the template in the console
$clientUserId = "***";      // to add an embedded recipient you must set their clientUserId property in addition to
                // the recipient name and email.  Whatever you set the clientUserId to you must use the same
                // value when requesting the signing URL

// construct the authentication header:
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1 - Login (retrieves baseUrl and accountId)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

//--- display results
echo "accountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 2 - Create an envelope with an Embedded recipient (uses the clientUserId property)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$data = array("accountId" => $accountId, 
    "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Embedded Signing Example",
    "templateId" => $templateId, 
    "templateRoles" => array(
        array( "roleName" => $templateRoleName, "email" => $email, "name" => $recipientName, "clientUserId" => $clientUserId )),
    "status" => "sent");                                                                    

$data_string = json_encode($data);  
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];
curl_close($curl);

//--- display results   
echo "Envelope created! Envelope ID: " . $envelopeId . "\n"; 

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 3 - Get the Embedded Singing View 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$data = array("returnUrl" => "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
    "authenticationMethod" => "None", "email" => $email, 
    "userName" => $recipientName, "clientUserId" => $clientUserId
);                                                                    

$data_string = json_encode($data);    
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes/$envelopeId/views/recipient" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$url = $response["url"];

//--- display results
echo "Embedded URL is: \n\n" . $url . "\n\nNavigate to this URL to start the embedded signing view of the envelope\n";
```

?>

And its successfully generate the link. But the problem is that I can`t see the tags I have set in the template, and  there is a list of fields in the left side .Is there any additional setting to display the tags in the documents itself for all the users who logged to access the document for signing.

Comment: What do you mean by "there's a list of fields on the left side"?  Can you post a screenshot of that or describe in more detail?  Usually when tags are on the left that means your in the Embedded Sending view, not Embedded Signing...

Comment: @Ergin Thank you for your response.Problem got solved.

Comment: What was the issue, were you getting the code samples mixed up?

Comment: Actually the issue was with the template role name.The role name I have mentioned in the code was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up here, looks like the issue was due to not matching your recipient to the roleName on the template.  For the benefit of the community, whenever you are creating an envelope / requesting a signature from a Template, you need to make sure you specify the same exact `roleName` in your API request as you gave the template role in the DocuSign Console.